# Disk not choosable on Startup Disk Creator

Tags: live-usb

I want to create a USB stick or CD with Ubuntu Live but when I go to Startup Disk Creator the place where you choose the disk is blank even though I have a good clean CD-R in the CD drive.  Do I need something other than CD-R to do this.  I was able to put it on a USB stick without a problem, and it said it was ready to boot from, but when I tried to boot from the stick it kept saying over and over "VesaMenu.C32: Not a COM32R Image" Then on the next line Boot.  I didn't know what to enter after the word Boot.

Comment: I have a USB stick with an older version of Ubuntu and when I put that in and press F9 (to change to boot from USB) it goes through the language and keyboard setup but then asks for a CD to be placed in the CD drive.  It accesses the USB stick but then wants a CD ??

Comment: probably you are using too old distribution Ubuntu what version it is ?

Answer (score 0):

VesaMenu.C23 is a GRUB boot file. The GRUB installation may have been corrupted.

If you are trying to burn an iso to live disc, look at [these](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/burn-a-dvd-on-ubuntu) instructions from Ubuntu.
If you are trying to create a live disc from your current installation, look at [this](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1762333) thread about `remastersys`.

A more specific question would help get a more specific answer, if these suggestions don't help...